# Matching values between two tables and finding the minimum of the two

Tags: excel

I have two tables each with a name and a value. 
I would like to find duplicate names between both tables and take the minimum value.

This is on Excel. I've tried various `VLookup()` and `MINIFS()` functions, but I am new to excel and don't understand all the examples.

The training set shows 35 for `Facebook`, and the Test set shows 37 for Facebook. I want my output to show 35, as that is the minimum value between the two tables.

***Table:***
[image]

Comment: Should be able to use an outer MIN with two inner MINIFS, one on each table.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @BigBen was saying for instance in Cell D2 you can try `=MIN(C2,MINIFS(F:F, E:E,B2))`. Do you want to first return a list of names that appeared on both tables only, and then find the minimum value based on the names?

Comment: @TerryW from the screenshot it looks like you might need a MINIFS for both tables, i.e. `C2` is not enough, but I could be wrong (multiple 'FaZE Clan' in table 2 and I assumed that this might be the case in table 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your datasets, you may be able to use MIN and MINIFS, something like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D:D,G2)>0,MIN(MINIFS(B:B,A:A,G2),MINIFS(E:E,D:D,G2)),MIN(MINIFS(B:B,A:A,G2)))
```

The COUNTIF is just to ensure that the other table has the set name, otherwise MINIFS returns 0. Depending on your setup, you might be able to use this simpler version:

```
=MIN(MINIFS(B:B,A:A,G2),MINIFS(E:E,D:D,G2))
```

*Note*: Slightly different test set table than your screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly as I wanted

Comment: Well cool, glad to help, wasn't sure I understood your setup 100%. There may be (probably is) a way to simplify, but it's late so I don't have the mental juice to dedicate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try following array formula

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A11=I2,B2:B11,""),IF(E2:E11=I2,F2:F11,""))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: I am using `Excel 2013`. So, I do not have `MINIF()` function.